# Replacing loop based col creation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, for-loop

Suppose I have `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']})
```

And `d`:

```
d = {'A': 1, 'B': 2}
```

I want to create `df['col2']` such that the values are fetched from `d` if they exist there, and if not equalize them with some fill value (say, `3`). I can do this by:

```
df['col2'] = pd.Series(np.NaN)

for k, v in d.items():
    df['col2'] = np.where(df['col1']==k, v, df['col2'])

df['col2'] = df.col2.fillna(3)
```

Which gives me:

```
df
    col1    col2
0   A       1.0
1   B       2.0
2   C       3.0
3   D       3.0
4   E       3.0
```

My question is: is it possible to achieve this without using a loop like a do?

Comment: Use `df['col2'] = df.col2.map(d).fillna(3)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
df['col1'].map(d).fillna(3)
```

to create the values for the new column.